# I want to convert series of characters into a string and compare with another string

Tags: java

**Sample Input 1:**

```
Enter the first letter:R
Enter the second letter:A
Enter the third letter:I
Enter the fourth letter:N
Enter the fifth letter:B
Enter the sixth letter:O
Enter the seventh letter:W
```

**Sample Output 1:**

```
RAINBOW
```

**Sample Input 2:**

```
Enter the first letter:R
Enter the second letter:E
Enter the third letter:I
Enter the fourth letter:N
Enter the fifth letter:B
Enter the sixth letter:O
Enter the seventh letter:W
```

**Sample Output 2:**

```
The spelling is wrong
```

**Code:**

```
public class spellcheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str1;
        String str2 = "rainbow";
        int i = 0;
        String a[] = new String[7];
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter:");
        a[0] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter:");
        a[1] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter:");
        a[2] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter:");
        a[3] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter:");
        a[4] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter:");
        a[5] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter:");
        a[6] = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

What should be the next step?

Answer (score 0):

```
String tmp = "";

for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j ++)
tmp += a[j];

System.out.println(tmp);
```

Output -

```
Enter the first letter:r
Enter the first letter:a
Enter the first letter:i
Enter the first letter:n
Enter the first letter:b
Enter the first letter:o
Enter the first letter:w
rainbow
```

To compare you can utilize the built in String function .equals -> tmp.equals("Otherstring")

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `char` array instead of a `String` array for storing the letters.
2. Create a `String` out of the `char` array and then compare the content.
3. Use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` to compare the spelling in a case-insensitive way.
4. Also, always follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of your class should be `SpellCheck` as per the naming conventions.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpellCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] suffix = { "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th" };
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        String str2 = "rainbow";
        char a[] = new char[str2.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            do {
                System.out.print(
                        "Enter the " + ((i + 1) + suffix[i % 100 > 9 && i % 100 < 13 ? 3 : i % 10]) + " letter: ");
                str = scan.nextLine();
                if (str.length() == 1) {
                    a[i] = str.charAt(0);
                }
            } while (str.length() != 1);
        }
        String str1 = new String(a);
        if (str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)) {
            System.out.println(str2.toUpperCase());
        } else {
            System.out.println("The spelling is wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the 1st letter: R
Enter the 2nd letter: A
Enter the 3rd letter: I
Enter the 4th letter: N
Enter the 5th letter: B
Enter the 6th letter: O
Enter the 7th letter: W
RAINBOW
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter the 1st letter: R
Enter the 2nd letter: E
Enter the 3rd letter: I
Enter the 4th letter: N
Enter the 5th letter: B
Enter the 6th letter: O
Enter the 7th letter: W
The spelling is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    str1 = str1 + a[i];
}
```

Then compare by str2.equals(str1)